# Heatmap representing the number of fixations

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am working in a heat map for some eye tracking data. I figured out how to do the heat map and it is very compelling. This is the code:

```
ggplot(eyematrixCorrectMatchControl, aes(x = CURRENT_FIX_X, y =CURRENT_FIX_Y)) +
annotation_raster(image, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf, interpolate = TRUE) +
stat_density2d(data= eyematrixCorrectMatchControl, aes(x = CURRENT_FIX_X, y =CURRENT_FIX_Y, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size= 10, bins= 50, geom='polygon') + 
theme_bw() +scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.01,0.25) , guide = FALSE) +
coord_cartesian(xlim= c(0,1024), ylim= c(0,768))+
scale_y_reverse() + 
theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks=element_blank(),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

With this code, I obtain this image: [image]

However, I don't understand some things. I thought that this code would give me a graph the number of fixations in a specific area (the more fixation the redder the area is). However, looking at the legend I am not sure what this graph shows. How can I obtain a graph showing the number of fixations? I would also like that the legend reflects the number of fixations, so the redder the more fixations. Any idea??

I edit to add some extra information that might be useful. In my original dataframe I also have a variable called fixation_index. I think that I have to include this variable somewhere, but not really sure.

Thanks!

Comment: The density sums to one, i.e. the legend refers to the fraction of fixations instead of the number.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Any idea about how to change that?

Comment: Perhaps you instead `fill = ..level..` you can use `fill = ..level.. * [total number of fixations]`

Comment: I answered a similar question in GIS contexts the other day. I wonder if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522378/density-count-in-heatmaps/32528744#32528744) will help you

Comment: you could also try `stat_binhex` / `geom_hex` to see if that provides enough granularity.

Answer (score 0):

Heatmap.2 offers a histogram option that correlates color with the density count. It looks like [this](https://learningomics.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/example.png).

Comment: thanks for your reply! Could you provide an example of code?

Comment: @unomas83: <blockquote>  heatmap.2(yourmatrixhere, xlab="choose your label at bottom here", col=brewer.pal(9,"Oranges"),trace="none", margins = c(4, 10), main = "Title at top here", key=TRUE) </blockquote>