# Making a map using "r" and ggmap of aviation accidents

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Currently I am trying to make a map of aviation accidents. I have the data I need and I have uploaded the correct library for ggmap.

I am having trouble figuring out how to put the latitude and longitude data from my data frame onto the map itself. I do not want to input 80k pieces of data individually.

`ggmap(usa) +  geom_point(data = aviaitiondata.df, mapping = aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = sector))`

I am very new at coding any help would be appriciated

Comment: You can aggregate the data by state, county, year, .... You can bin the data with `stat_bin2d` or `stat_density2d`, etc.

Comment: See if [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24615674/8245406) can be of help.

Comment: Thank you. This is not exactly what I'm looking for but it does have some interesting things in it that I can use later.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make an API with google in r

`register_google("api.key")`

The key was made using a google maps license.
This let me make the map that I needed to make to place the data